Connected counters
The basic idea is that I am going to have examples of english sentences and then alternative formalizations of them.
I want an arabic counter (‘eg’ in MWE) for the english sentences and an alphabetical “sub counter” (‘subeg’ in MWE) for the formalizations.
These counters will work similarly to linguex’s \ex. I think linguex won’t work because \a. is always on a new line and doesn’t include the \ex. counter.  And there is no “principled” way of going out of order, I would have to manually manipulate the counter. If this is wrong, I’m happy to see a linguex solution.
I want to be able to able to swap between counter examples and subcounters out of order.
For example give two english sentences then go back and the give the formalizations of the first one. My MWE does this. But I want the subcounter to be connected to the counter so that it knows how many formalizations are given for that sentence rather than “globally”. My MWE doesn’t do this (subcounter ‘subeg’ is only reset to 0 by calling counter ‘eg’)
I want to be able to refer to the full counter string (eg.subeg) at any point in the document. My MWE doesn’t do this. My attempt to do so `\ref{neg}' just returns the value of the subcounter as an arabic numeral. I can refer to the counter, but I would like if the ref returned the period also.
I have used new command because it’s the definition type I deal with the most but maybe a theorem like environment is better.
Here is my MWE attempt
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{eg}
\newcommand\egs[1]{\refstepcounter{eg}  \setcounter{subeg}{0}
\arabic{eg}. \label{#1}}
\newcounter{subeg}
\newcommand\subegs[2]{\refstepcounter{subeg}
\ref{#1}.\alph{subeg}. \label{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{egs}{tom}
    No-one likes Tom 
\end{egs}

\begin{egs}{happy}
    Everyone is happy 
\end{egs}

\begin{subegs}{tom}{pos}
    $\forall x \neg L(x, t)$
\end{subegs}

\begin{subegs}{tom}{neg}
    $\neg \exists x L(x, t)$
\end{subegs}

\ref{tom}

\begin{egs}{sad}
    Everyone is sad
\end{egs}

\ref{neg} 

\begin{subegs}{sad}{base}
    $\forall x S(x)$
\end{subegs}

\begin{subegs}{happy}{notsad}
    $\forall x \neg S(x)$
\end{subegs}

\end{document} 

Current output. Notice 2.b. (should be 2.a.)

Here is what I would like it to output instead.


Can you please add what your code outputs at the moment, so the problem is easier to see? Thank you

Are the spaces you're adding in your definitions deliberate? Also, you're using \begin etc. even though you've defined a command. Do you want to be able to say \egs{tom} or \begin{egs}{tom} more than once and, if so, what should happen to the counters?

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but I do recommend using a syntax which reflects the structure of the macros you create. So, if you use \newcommand, use e.g. \egs and \subegs. If you want \begin{egs} etc., create environments instead.
Here's a command version which sticks to \newcommand. The basic strategy is to create a new counter for each \egs which is then used for the \subegs associated with that counter. To get the desired output from \ref, we just need to change the format of \theeg and \thesubeg.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{eg}
\newcommand\egs[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{eg}%
  \newcounter{#1subeg}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1subeg\endcsname{\ref{#1}\alph{#1subeg}.}%
  \theeg\label{#1}}
\newcommand\subegs[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{#1subeg}%
  \csname the#1subeg\endcsname\label{#2}}

\renewcommand \theeg{\arabic{eg}.}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\egs{tom}
No-one likes Tom 

\egs{happy}
Everyone is happy 

\subegs{tom}{pos}
$\forall x \neg L(x, t)$

\subegs{tom}{neg}
$\neg \exists x L(x, t)$

\ref{tom}

\egs{sad}
Everyone is sad

\ref{neg} 

\subegs{sad}{base}
$\forall x S(x)$

\subegs{happy}{notsad}
$\forall x \neg S(x)$

\end{document} 


